# Docker swarm : org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment

Tags: java, networking, apache-kafka, containers, docker-swarm

I am trying to containerize a java server application which uses **kafka**. I observed this behavior,

**Case 1 : Running as a single container uses bridge network**

In this case it works well. So no problem.

**Case 2 : Running as a single service uses overlay network (Swarm mode)**

In this case, I got `org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException` because of this unsuccessful connection,

```
WARN [2019-12-06T14:05:44,668] RequestSendThread: warn(): [Controller-0-to-broker-0-send-thread]: Controller 0's connection to broker 10.255.3.64:10101 (id: 0 rack: null) was unsuccessful
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Failed to connect within 30000 ms
        at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.brokerReady(ControllerChannelManager.scala:270) [kafka_2.12-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at kafka.controller.RequestSendThread.doWork(ControllerChannelManager.scala:223) [kafka_2.12-1.0.0.jar:?]
        at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:64) [kafka_2.12-1.0.0.jar:?]
```

I don't know much about **kafka** and can't understand **How overlay network affects the kafka process while it works well in bridge network** ?

**Edit 1:**

Almost found the problem... In docker swarm mode, container have **two ip address** because of the two interfaces `bridge` and `overlay`. The ips are `endpoint:172.19.0.3, 10.255.3.65`.

While trying to connect to the container (inside from the same container),

**Bridge I/F :** `172.19.0.3 : 10101` - can connect. means `telent 172.19.0.3 10101` works.
**Overlay I/F :**`10.155.3.65 : 10101` - can't connect to the port, but can ping works.

The virtual ip `10.155.3.65` which is used by kafka that makes `TimeoutException`.

**Cannot connect to the localhost port while using overlay ip (but can ping). Why this scenario happens ?**

Comment: Please show your broker and docker configuration files. For example, you've change a port somewhere because `10101` is not Kafka or Zookeeper

Comment: @cricket_007. I don't think it is a configuration mistake. bcoz it works while inside normal container with bridge interface. problem arises while it uses `overlay` network interface ip. Kind of network environment problem... I have updated my question with my latest observations as **Edit 1**...

Comment: 1) Testing a local container doesn't prove network connection just works. 2) Where and why have you set port 10101? 3) Have you read this? https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: @cricket_007 I believe, there must be a lot of reasons for ur questions. In my scenario, the assigned default overlay network doesn't allow communication. `--attachable` solved this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

My bad. I have used `default` overlay that made the problem.. https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/ .

Created an `--attachable` custom overlay network solved this issue.

```
docker network create -d overlay --attachable my-attachable-overlay
```